# Servlet error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Java Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I know that there were similar problems already, but non of the solutions worked for me. I checked the directories and I edited my `web.xml file a couple of times but it still does not work.

I am writing a simple servlet in Java running on Tomcat and I am getting the error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /WorkshopForm/MainWorkshopForm
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My servlet class is:

```
package workshop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(description = "This registration form", urlPatterns = { 
"/WorkshopForm" })


public class WorkshopForm {
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 13425L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String participantName = request.getParameter("participantName");
    String participantSurname = request.getParameter("participantSurname");
    String participantEmail = request.getParameter("participantEmail");

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("Welcome" + participantName + " " + participantSurname + " " + participantEmail); 
    }       
}
```

}

My `web.xml`:

[image: screenshot web file]

Tree in Eclipse:

[image: screenshot directories]

Is it a problem with the `web.xml` file? I am thinking that maybe I have some mismatch with names or paths but I tried to solved it already and no idea why it is not working.

Comment: what url are you targetting

Comment: "MainWorkshopForm" this URL is nowhere mentioned in your code. Why do you expect a resource there?

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern `/WorkshopForm` matches only the exact URL path `/WorkshopForm`. If you want the servlet to also handle longer paths like `/WorkshopForm/MainWorkshopForm`, you need to change the URL pattern to `/WorkshopForm/*`. Then you can call `request.getPathInfo()` in your servlet code to obtain the variable part of the path.

Another alternative is to use some JAX-RS framework to handle the mapping from URL paths to Java methods that handle individual paths.